# Can somebody help me with these trigger errors in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have these tables:

- Person (id_pers, name, phone, address, birthdate)
- Book (book_id, title, nr_of_pages, copies, genre)
- Loan(book_id, loan_id, dateL, dateR, nr_of_days)

**birthdate** is of datatype **DATE**;
**loan_id** takes value from the **id_pers**;
**dateL** - loan date;
**dateR** - return date;
**nr_of_days** represents the return term (how many days the loan may take);

Define a trigger for:
Ensure that when adding a loan, the nr_of_days is proportionate to
nr_of_pages taking into account the age of the person making the loan. Between 18-25 years,
30 pages/day; between 26-65 years, 20 pages/day; over 65 years, 40 pages/day.

I tried using this trigger but it compiles with errors

```
create or replace TRIGGER Update_Days
BEFORE INSERT ON Loan
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE age INT;
    SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, CURRENT_DATE) INTO age
    FROM Person
    WHERE id_pers = NEW.loan_id;

    IF age BETWEEN 18 AND 25 THEN
        SET NEW.nr_of_days = NEW.nr_of_pages / 30;
    ELSEIF age BETWEEN 26 AND 65 THEN
        SET NEW.nr_of_days = NEW.nr_of_pages / 20;
    ELSE
        SET NEW.nr_of_days = NEW.nr_of_pages / 40;
    END IF;
END;
```

[errors i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YXBs.png)

Comment: Declare section should have been before Begin section ..

Comment: more errors, but ty tho

Comment: There's a large number of errors: remove the SET verb, replace = with :=, and there's no datediff function in Oracle, just do birthdate-sysdate (result in days) (plus first remark above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `SET` is not used in PL/SQL
- In PL/SQL, the assignment operator is `:=` and not `=`
- The `NEW` record is referenced using bind variable syntax of `:NEW`
- `DATEDIFF` is not a valid function in Oracle.
- The `DECLARE` section goes before `BEGIN`.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Update_Days
  BEFORE INSERT ON loan
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  age INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(CURRENT_DATE, birthdate)/12)
  INTO   age
  FROM   Person
  WHERE  id_pers = :NEW.loan_id;

  :NEW.nr_of_days := :NEW.nr_of_pages / CASE
                                        WHEN age BETWEEN 18 AND 25 THEN 30
                                        WHEN age BETWEEN 26 AND 65 THEN 20
                                        ELSE 40
                                        END;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qs9pI7a-)